# dmarc reports and invalid sender ip

Tags: email, dmarc

We sometimes get an aggregated report where some mails fails due to invalid ip. That ip is not allowed to send emails from our domain (I guess it is spam. this IP does not belong to us) - is there any recommendation for what to do?

We only use our mail server for sending email.

Should we contact the operator the IP belongs to and notify they have somebody sending spam?
Or is there noting to do about it?

Comment: You can often tell from the name registered for the IP when the mail in question was forwarded as-is by some freemail provider.

Answer (score 1):

This report means your DMARC works as intended.

Did you set in the policy: "reject all non-signed emails coming from unspecified address, also send me reports from time to time"? Remote servers obey this: they reject such mails and report that to you.

You may complain to abuse teams if you want to. But you are not obligued to do that.